# What is the better way for update table 2 with table 1 php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

What is the better way for update table 2 with table 1 php mysqli ?

for me, use while loop and update row

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_1";
$result = mysqli_query($db_mysqli, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $money = $row['money'];     
    $db_mysqli->query("Update table_2 Set money = '$money' WHERE id = '$id'");      
}
?>
```

I want to know php have code that process in 1 step for update table 2 with table 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

just change your query to

```
Update table_2 Set money = (select money from table_1 where table_1.id = table_2.id)
```

Your entire code will be :

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$query = "Update table_2 Set money = (select money from table_1 where table_1.id = table_2.id)";
$db_mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

Comment: like this `$db_mysqli->query("Update table_2 Set money = (select money from table_1 where table_1.id = table_2.id)");` ?